# Timestamp Regex python (2016-06-22 07:55:35,232 )

Tags: python

I am finding difficult to form a regex for the above timestamp pattern in python. I have to search for the timestamp that matches this pattern in a list in python .

Eg,

2016-06-22 07:55:35,232 [12] INFO

In the above line i have to search 2016-06-22 07:55:35,232 .

I have tried with the following regex but it does not seem to work :

```
"^\\d{4}[-]?\\d{1,2}[-]?\\d{1,2} \\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}[,]?\\d{1,3}$"
```

Kindly help

Thanks

Comment: Yes , i tried . This is the closest i could come up with .                        "^\\d{4}[-]?\\d{1,2}[-]?\\d{1,2} \\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}[,]?\\d{1,3}$"            but am not sure , if its correct.

Comment: @Gautham Please edit your question to include that.

Comment: What are you using to produce the date? Do you want all dates? Or just that date & time?

Comment: I would get rid of that `$` at the end. That'll make it so it can only match if the timestamp appears at the end of the string, but it looks like after your timestamp in your example you have `[12] INFO`.

Comment: it worked with the following regex :                                                                 "^\\d{4}[-]?\\d{1,2}[-]?\\d{1,2} \\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}[,]?\\d{1,3}"  , removing $ at the end worked fine for me .   Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `$` sign at the end -- remove it from your regex. You do not get anything back because `$` (end of line) does not match `[12] INFO`

```
>>> re.findall("^\\d{4}[-]?\\d{1,2}[-]?\\d{1,2} \\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}[,]?\\d{1,3}$", '2016-06-22 07:55:35,232 [12] INFO')
[]
>>> re.findall("^\\d{4}[-]?\\d{1,2}[-]?\\d{1,2} \\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}[,]?\\d{1,3}", '2016-06-22 07:55:35,232 [12] INFO')
['2016-06-22 07:55:35,232']
```

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulating your regex with `^` and `$` ensures that the string will only ever be matched by your regex if the regex matches the entire string, since `^` signifies beginning of the string and `$` signifies the end. If you want it to be able to match anywhere, you should remove both the `^` and the `$`. If you only want the timestamp to match when it is the start of the string, keep the `^` and just remove the `$`, which is what is currently blocking you from getting a match since you have `[12] INFO` at the end of your string.

Comment: Addendum: `^...$` will also match the beginning>end of one line in multiline mode

Comment: @Delioth Right. That's a good thing to note. `$` matches the end of the string or to just before a newline character.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern works fine, but you are only matching at the end of string because of `$`.

If you want to match just this:

```
2016-06-22 07:55:35,232
```

You can use this regular expression.

```
(?P<date>\d{4}[-]?\d{1,2}[-]?\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}[,]?\d{1,3})
```

You can try it online at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nS1sA9/1)